# How to access elements of a Dictionary / List from a call to Mailchimp

Tags: python, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm new to Python and would really appreciate a bit of help.  I need to retrieve information from Mailchimp on all the Audiences (mailing lists) and then pull back information on the members of those Audiences (the people receiving the emails).

So far I have connected to Mailchimp via their API and I can pull back all the Audience records.  I only need the Id of the Audience which I would ultimately pass to the Member function on the API.

At the moment I'm struggling to iterate through the results and only see the Id's.  The code that I have written so far is this:

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

client = MailChimp(mc_api='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

cpc_lists = client.lists.all(count=500, fields="lists.id")

for x in cpc_lists.values():
    print(x)
```

The result that comes back looks like this:

```
[{'id': '014b147652'}, {'id': '02c607ffae'}, {'id': '02f888a727'}, {'id': '04caf23020'}, {'id': '094330adf3'}, {'id': '0a1f431e1d'}, {'id': '0a42ad0921'}, {'id': '0bb88d4033'}, {'id': '0dda6c7b86'}, {'id': '0e53b36cd7'}, {'id': '0f4c053cf8'}, {'id': '102f77d088'}, {'id': '12dbe3b548'}]
```

How would I loop through the data and access the value part of each id so I can then pass it to another API call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've connected to many of the endpoints for Mailchimp via Python at my work. I doctored what I use successfully to be more generalized, but let me know if this works for you. The Mailchimp API can be quickly reproduced once you start to get a good base script.

To answer your question directly, see the below script. With the sample output provided, you would need to insert into a dataframe and you should be good.

```
import pandas as pd

your_data = [{'id': '014b147652'}, {'id': '02c607ffae'}, {'id': '02f888a727'}, {'id': '04caf23020'}, {'id': '094330adf3'}, {'id': '0a1f431e1d'}, {'id': '0a42ad0921'}, {'id': '0bb88d4033'}, {'id': '0dda6c7b86'}, {'id': '0e53b36cd7'}, {'id': '0f4c053cf8'}, {'id': '102f77d088'}, {'id': '12dbe3b548'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(your_data)
display(df.head(10))
```

**For a More Robust Option That I personally use to paginate requests:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


# MC Docs #
# https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/get-lists-info/


API_KEY = 'INSERT YOUR API KEY HERE'


def flatten_json(nested_json):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')

        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)

    return out


def getTheMasterDataFrame(ID):
    url = 'https://anystring:' + str(ID) + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?\
    fields=lists.id,lists.web_id,lists.name,lists.date_created,lists.stats.member_count,lists.stats.total_contacts\
    ,lists.stats.unsubscribe_count,lists.stats.cleaned_count,lists.stats.campaign_count,lists.stats.open_rate\
    ,lists.stats.click_rate,lists.stats.last_sub_date,lists.stats.last_unsub_date\
    &sort_field=date_created&sort_dir=DESC&count=1000&since_create_time=2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    flattened_data_list = []

    for list in data.get("lists"):
        flattened_data = flatten_json(list)
        flattened_data_list.append(flattened_data)

    mailchimp_df = pd.DataFrame([flattened_data_list])
    mailchimp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(flattened_data_list)


    return mailchimp_df


def main():
    master_df = getTheMasterDataFrame(API_KEY)

    print("Finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```